# How to connect to an MQTT server using a SAS token, in LwIP?

Tags: azure, mqtt, lwip, mbedtls

I'm know working on establishing a connection to an Azure test IOT hub but using a **SAS token** and not a **device certificate** as mentioned here in the Azure certificates change

[image]

I was using this function from LwIP stack to make a tls config using my device certifcate

```
altcp_tls_create_config_client_2wayauth
```

and

```
mqtt_client_connect
```

to connect to the server
What I need to know is:

- Should I use another **altcp_tls** function to connect using a SAS token?
- How can I check that the TLS handshake is done? because this is what I need to know

I appreciate any help

I tried to use the connection string from the article as a client password in MQTT client parameters, but I don't know if the TLS handshake is done or not